# Styling navigation bar: alternative to display:table/table-cell

Tags: html, css

For a website project, we have a simple navigation bar where each link is outlined in gray, and hovering outlines it in black.

I got it working and my code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/BpjK8/ -- although I admit it's a little dirty and 'hacky' in a way. (You can see when hovering link A, the border of link B beside it is visible, making it somewhat distracting.)

My question is: can this be done in a better way without using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`? It would be nice if the answer involved `display: inline` or `float: left` but I can't get the border effect working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/BpjK8/3/)

Of course! Add:

```
body{
    text-align:center; /* centre the content */
}
```

Then set your `ul` to `display:inline-block` to allow it to be subject to the centering, and give your `li`:

```
float:left;
display:block;
```

So they display one after another correctly.

You may not want to centre your entire document however, so instead you may want to wrap the `ul` in a `div` with `text-align:center;` set.

Comment: Looks good! Any chance you know how to get rid of that pesky gray border to the right of the hovered link too?

Comment: Magical. Although hovering on the last link seems to shift the <ul> to the left by 1px?

Answer (score 1):

Try this css:

```
ul {
    margin: 50px auto;
    list-style:none;
}

li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid #CECECE;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 2px;
}

li:last-child {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid #CECECE;
    border-right: 1px solid #CECECE;
    padding: 2px;
}

li:hover {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    padding: 1px;
}

a {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #000;
}
```